# Why isn't there NSArrayController for the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, arrays, nsarraycontroller

Why isn't there NSArrayController for the iPhone?
Will there ever be an NSArrayController for the iPhone?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> Why isn't there NSArrayController for the iPhone?

Because it's part of the Application Kit. The iPhone doesn't have Application Kit; it has UIKit instead.

Also, it exists on the Mac to complement Bindings, which doesn't exist on the iPhone.

> Will there ever be an NSArrayController for the iPhone?

Ask Apple. Better yet, [file an enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com/). File one for Bindings while you're at it, since there's not much point in having NSArrayController without it.

Comment: Perhaps I'm being juvenile, but is it impossible to create a poor man's nsarraycontroller, and in a sense "fake" bindings by using lots of key-value observations between a core data entity and an nsarray?  Granted, I'm more of a tourist when it comes to Core Data, but I'm surprised there's just *nothing* for this.

Answer (score 7):

While it is not the same as NSArrayController, NSFetchedResultsController serves many of the same purposes.

Of course, we're not allowed to talk about NSFetchedResultsController yet, but I wonder what would happen if you searched the Apple docs for it?

Just saw this old answer of mine needed an update: It is allowed to talk about NSFetchedResultsController now.