# IB: Where is the Bindings Pane

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, binding, pane

Cocoa newbie here...

I know this sounds stupid but I can't find the Bindings Pane in Interface Builder. I have the latest xCode( 3.2.3 ) but tried with other versions too, still the same. The Tools menu does not list it and Cmd-4 opens up the Identity inspector.

[Screenshot](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/043abb03f8.jpg)

What could be the cause?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're programming on the iPhone. (I think I saw a UIKit reference in that image.)

Unfortunately they are not implemented for the iPhone and so you can not use binding in Interface Builder.

[Bindings using Interface Builder (for iPhone apps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394408/bindings-using-interface-builder-for-iphone-apps)